# How to parse base64 image from JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, base64

What's the reason that I can't parse a base64 string from a JSON request? when I make it a small string it works.

To clarify a little:

```
    else if([connection isEqual:self.appearanceConnection]){

        NSArray *arrayOfAppearances = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        NSLog(@"het aantal appearances is: %i", arrayOfAppearances.count);
        [self syncAppearances:arrayOfAppearances];



    }
```

When I edit it to a small string, I get the response that the length of the received array is 1. If I change it again to the base 64 of the image, the length is 0.

http://cl.ly/image/470Z0X1P3K1b (image form JSON response)

[image]

The error I get on the String:

[image]

Comment: example? ... you are decoding the json first right?

Comment: Are you converting the base64 string to data and initialising an image from that?

Comment: There is no reason; works fine. Perhaps you're doing something wrong in your code that you haven't posted?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear, updated my post now

Comment: Anyone who has an idea? Is it possible that the base64 string is to long, cause i can parse a small string?

Comment: Why are you using the `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated answer:

You now inform us that `JSONObjectWithData` is reporting an error:

> Unterminated string around character 62

Character 62 is the start of the logo. I'm not seeing the end of the JSON in any of your screen snapshots. It looks like it's getting cut off.

You haven't shown us how you are populating `data`, but it looks almost like you're using a `NSURLConnection` but trying to parse in `didReceiveData` as opposed to waiting for the full results and only invoking the the JSON parse in `connectionDidFinishLoading`. `NSURLConnection` will break a long response into several calls to `didReceiveData` and you have to append all of those `NSData` to a single `NSMutableData`, and only try to parse it when it's done retrieving everything.

You either need to (a) show us the code where you're loading data and/or (b) share the full JSON. Either your JSON isn't properly terminated or you're trying to parse it before the whole thing is downloaded (probably the latter).

---

Original answer:

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but your line that says:

```
NSArray *arrayOfAppearances = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

should simply be:

```
NSArray *arrayOfAppearances = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&error];
```

The `JSONObjectWithData` method takes a `NSData`, not a `NSString`.

And, if you're not getting anything returned from this method, you should examine the contents of `error` and see what it says.

If you're still unable to figure out what the problem is, perhaps you can share the full JSON response with us (give us a URL or upload it somewhere) and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, it was stupid indeed to translate it to a String first... The error says: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unterminated string around character 62.) UserInfo=0x8336280 {NSDebugDescription=Unterminated string around character 62.}   So my guess is that there is e character that splits the string or something? do you know how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I did cut out the NSJSONReadingAllowFragments, I copy/pasted to much there. You're absolutely right, I did try to parse the data in the didreceivedata, I'm gone try nog do this in the didfinishlaunching method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With a big thanks to @Rob!

Here a little summary:

- Create a variable NSMutableData (don't forget to initialise in the viewdidload)
- In the didReceiveData, you append the data to your mutable data using [self.appearancedata appendData:data];
- In the connectionDidFinishLoading you parse your JSON

Comment: Excellent. FYI, a minor detail, but often people will initialize the `NSMutableData` object in [`didReceiveResponse`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:didReceiveResponse:), because that's when you know if the connection succeeded and is about to proceed. But I'm glad you solved your issue!